# How can I calculate the PI of (simple) exponential smoothing?

Tags: r, prediction-interval, exponential-smoothing

I would like to calculate the prediction intervals of exponential smoothing. In R there is a function (ses in a forecast package) which calculates the point forecast and also the prediction intervals.

Here is a little example:

```
a = c(0,158,176,242,331,262,343,288)

library(forecast)

ses(a, h = 3)
```

I would like to know the formula of "Lo 95" and "Hi 95" (from the output)

And as I noticed when I predict forward multiple periods (like the example, when I set the h = 3) the PI is getting wider and wider. I also would like to know the formula of it.

Thans for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $h$-step forecast variance is given by
$$v_{T+h|T} = \sigma^2[1+\alpha^2(h-1)]$$
where $\sigma^2$ is the residual variance and $\alpha$ is the smoothing parameter.

So if $\hat{y}_{T+h|T}$ is the point forecast, then the 95% prediction interval is $\hat{y}_{T+h|T} \pm 1.96\sqrt{v_{T+h|T}}$.

This is discussed in Chapter 6 of my [2008 Springer book](http://amzn.com/3540719164/?tag=otexts-20)

Comment: Thanks for Your help!

I just wondering why should I calculate with normal distribution insted of Student's t-distribution (I have a small n).

And one more thing: I have a population data (not a sample data) should I have to change the formula on account of this information?

Comment: Use the t distribution if you like.

Comment: Thanks! And what about the second part of my question? (I have a population data (not a sample data) should I have to change the formula on account of this information?)